# Entity framework validation in separate class error No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

This is my generated class Customer

```
namespace Winpro
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Blocked = false;
        this.Code = "#00000";
        this.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    ...
```

ValidateCustomer class

```
namespace Winpro
{
public partial class Customer
{
    partial void OnCodeChanging(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("value cannot be null or empty");
    }
}
}
```

Solution has two projects :

```
+ Database (model and validation) <-- here I'm creating ValidateCustomer class
+ Winpro   (winApp)
```

`Error  1   No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'Winpro.Customer.OnCodeChanging(string)'   C:\Users\..\Projects\Winpro\Database\ValidateCustomer.cs    12  22  Database`

I've read that this is namespace issue but as you can see from posted code that all classes are in same namespace?

What can I do to correct this error.

My previous SO question from where I got this code and explanation :

[Where to put functions and validation code Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244777/where-to-put-functions-and-validation-code-entity-framework)

Comment: Have you tried adding `public` to your `OnCodeChanging()`?

Comment: Also, you say, "I'm creating ValidateCustomer class in `Database`."  shouldn't you be putting it in the `Winpro` namespace?

Comment: Both project are in same namespace `Winpro`. Cannot add `public` because partial method cannot have access modifiers

Comment: SOLUTION: I had to change template

Comment: Glad you found your answer.  You may want to elaborate a little in case someone has a similar problem in the future - your experience could help them, too.